# quando coloco um numero pequeno no meu algoritmo ele funciona, porém se o número é grande o programa retorna 0

Tags: c, int

quando coloco um numero pequeno no meu algoritmo ele funciona, porém se o número é grande o programa retorna 0, tentei colocar unsigned int, long, etc e nao funcionou... heis o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
*/

int primo(int num);//declarando a função
int menorDiv();
const long numz = 600851475143;

int main(){

    //1 - pegar os divisores do numero
    //2 - verificar se esse divisor é primo
    //3 - pegar o maior divisor primo do numero 600851475143

    int i, maior = 0, primao;
    for ( i = 1; i <= menorDiv(); i++){
        if( i % 2 == 0)
            continue;
        if ( primo(i)  == 0){//se for primo
            if ( numz % i == 0){
                primao = i;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d", primao);
    return 0;
}

int menorDiv(){//pega o menor divisor do numero grandao
    int i, menor;
    for ( i = 1; i < numz; i++){
        if( numz % i == 0){
            menor =  (float)numz/i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return menor;
}

int primo(int num){
    int i, contador = 0;

    for ( i = 1; i <= num; i++){
        if( num % i == 0){
            contador++;
        }
    }
    if ( contador == 2){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Fiz algumas edições no código e a versão final ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
*/
const long long num = 600851475143;
long long menorDiv(long long num);
long long primo(long long i);

int main(){

    // 1 - pegar os divisores primos
    // 2 - pegar o maior

    long long i, primu;//declara i como long long
    for ( i = 0; i < menorDiv(num); i++){
        if ( primo(i) == 0){//caso seja primo faça
            if( num % i == 0){
                primu = i;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%ld", primu);
    return 0;
}
long long menorDiv(long long num){//pega o menor numero que seja divisivel pelo numero para que o programa nao continue rodando apos esse numero
    long long i, result;
    for ( i = 1; i <= num; i++){
        if( num % i == 0){
            result = num/i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
long long primo(long long i){
    int contador = 0;
    long long j;
    for ( j = 1; j < i; j++){
        if( i % j == 0){
            contador++;
        }
    }
    if( contador == 2){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Porém ainda sem sucesso, o código fica rodando e não para... parece que entrou em looping infinito, mas não encontrei algum lugar que isso possa ter ocorrido

Comment: quando coloco 13195 no numz o resultado da 29 que está correto, mas ao colocar 600851475143 retorna 0, deveria retornar 6857

Answer (score 2):

Você declarou:

```
const long numz = 600851475143;
```

e aqui faz:

```
int i, menor;
for ( i = 1; i < numz; i++){
```

Note que i é um int e um int não comporta este valor de numz.
Talvez você devesse utilizar long long para tais variáveis e double para a divisão.

Comment: assim ?:
    long long i;
    double menor;

Comment: Também vale mencionar que com `printf("%d", minha_var)` o valor de um `long` não será imprimido corretamente, tem que utilizar `printf("%li", minha_var)`

Comment: Sim. Talvez até fazer a divisão com operandos long long.

Answer (score 2):

Você deverá declarar a variávei menor e i, como const long

```
const long menor;
const long i;

for ( i = 1; i < numz; i++){...
```

Obs.: Também deverá trocar todas as variáveis *int* para *const long*.

Comment: Creio que não tem muito sentido declarar ai como const se o valor de i vai variar no loop.

Answer (score 0):

comecei a refazer o código do zero e consegui resolver o problema, heis o código otimizado e funcional:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>//biblioteca booleana

/*
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
*/
bool primo(long num);//declarando a funcao
int main(){

    for ( long i = 1; i < 600851475143; i++){
        if ( 600851475143 % i == 0 && primo(600851475143/i)){//caso seja primo e divisivel pelo numero retorna esse valor
            printf("%li", 600851475143/i);
            return 0;    
        }
    }
}

bool primo( long num){//checa se o numero e primo
    long i;
    for ( i = 2; i < num; i++){
        if( num % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

dica para alguns que estão começando: Às vezes é melhor recomeçar e resolver o problema desde o início do que resolver uma parte do problema e mais tarde ter que resolver novamente e novamente e assim sucessivamente! "Corte o mal pela raiz"